# Get data from one editor field and pass that into another editor field

Tags: theming, nodes, javascript, blocks, wysiwyg

I have no idea if this is even possible, but I figured I'd ask anyway.
I'm working with a site that is on Drupal 8, and long story short, we don't have access to extending nor updating much so any custom layouts that we would need or want to manipulate is all done via JS and CSS on the front end.
With that being said, I was wondering if it's *possible* to get data from one editor field and pass that into another. So for this example, I would try to take the content that was in a "title" field and then pass that into some JS code that is in another one. Something like this:

[image]

Which would then output something like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('h2:contains("Title for thing...")').attr("id", "enroll");
});
</script>
```

Again, I have **no clue** if something like this is remotely possible. I new to Drupal but my hands are kinda tied when it comes to adding new stuff to the editor (has to get approved, etc, etc) and so I'm looking for ways that I can try to "future proof" anything that I can make but then if someone edits the content it doesn't run the risk of breaking the layout. I know, not ideal by any means, but I'm just trying out some ideas if possible.

Comment: It is possible, in the grand scheme of web development.  But if you are resorting to such approaches because you cannot customise your drupal instance at all, then you can't do this in a 'drupal way', where such behaviours are part of the form API `$form`.  In fact, you presumably can't even add a layer of hacky javascript to do it in the DOM, if you can't extend or change your drupal theme(s).  In which case, I think your only option would be a greasemonkey style userscript, in which case, I'm afraid it's not a drupal question anymore and would presumably be deemed off-topic here.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu - Thanks for your input! Yeah, for this particular instance I have a very limited ability to make any custom CSS updates within the layouts since I don't have control over, we, much. I understand there's a reason for the way things are, but it's tough when a request comes in to make a change when the layout doesn't offer that. So I'm trying to avoid doing to do too much hacking within the editor as to prevent issues if someone changes or updates the content later on.